# RAID 1, error "PCI training error" after power surge on DELL POWER EDGE R410

Tags: hardware-raid

After a power surge a DELL POWER EDGE R410 is no longer booting, the error is "PCIe Training Error: Embedded NIC 1".

On this server there is a RAID 1.
Can I remove one HDD and view data on another computer if I mount it directly - no RAID controler?

EDIT: I assumed the motherboard is burned so I can only try to recover the data. Is there another way to recover from this error?

Comment: Why is this question down rated?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES, a HDD from a hardware RAID1 can be mounted as a simple drive without any RAID controler.